# Ajax in Backbone fetch finishes after fetch call exits, so no success/fail event in fetch call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, fetch

In my Backbone view initialize, I call an overridden fetch. Fetch checks if data is in localStorage, and if not, pulls data with ajax and populates into localStorage.

However, the ajax call takes some time, so the fetch method returns before ajax finishes. Thus, the original fetch call never triggers the success event.

**How do I trigger the success event from inside fetch?  I also need to pass the data (once ajax completes) to initialize (either somehow returning it, or making the success event call fetch() again to pull from localStorage).**

Thanks!

*Initialize within appview:*

```
initialize: function() {
  var imageList = new ImageList(),
      simageel = $(this.el).find('#imagec'),
      simageView;
  imageList.fetch({
    error: function() { console.log(arguments); },
    success: function(collection) {
      collection.each(function (model) {
        simageView = new SImageView({
          model: model
        });
        simageel.html(simageView.render().el);
        console.log('Fetch success.');  // Never fires
      });
    }
  });
```

*Overridden fetch in collection:*

```
fetch: function(options) {
  if(!localStorage.getItem("image")) {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: '[url]'  //Could add async but how to trigger render from this function?
      }).done(function(response) {            
        console.log("Fetched"); 
        $.each(response.items, function(i, item) {
          self.create(item);  // saves model to local storage
        });
      }).fail(function(response) {
         console.log("Failure in fetch");
      });
  } else {
      // fetch from localStorage works fine
      return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetch: function(options) {
  if(!localStorage.getItem("image")) {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: '[url]'  //Could add async but how to trigger render from this function?
      }).done(function(response) {            
        console.log("Fetched"); 
        $.each(response.items, function(i, item) {
          self.create(item);  // saves model to local storage
        });
        options.success(self); //call success func
        self.trigger('sync', self, response, options); //fire sync event
      }).fail(function(response) {
         console.log("Failure in fetch");
         options.error(responce) //call error func
      });
  } else {
      // fetch from localStorage works fine
      return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
  }
}
```

Once you start using async function like $.ajax,you cannot use return value for next method.You need to call callback instead.

Original Backbone fire `sync` event when model/collection finish fetching.
So do the same thing in your code. and do `listenTo` in the View constructor to run the next method.

```
initialize: function() {
  var imageList = new ImageList(),
      simageel = $(this.el).find('#imagec'),
      simageView;
  this.listenToOnce(imageList,"sync",function(){
    console.log("call next method what you want to do after fetching's finished");
  });
  imageList.fetch({
    error: function() { console.log(arguments); },
    success: function(collection) {
      collection.each(function (model) {
        simageView = new SImageView({
          model: model
        });
        simageel.html(simageView.render().el);
        console.log('Fetch success.');  // Never fires
      });
    }
  });
```